# How to print 2 characters in C without using logical operators?

Tags: c, logic

I'm working on a program that determines a type of torus, volume of that torus, surface area, and cost of fabricating it/painting it based upon 2 input radii: rmajor and rminor.  *The only complicated part is I can't use logical operators or comparison statements.*  I am able to determine the surface area, volume, and costs related to the torus but I can't determine the manufacturing code (as shown in the print statements).  The corresponding Manufacturing codes are as follows:

1. Ri: ring torus (rmajor > rminor)
2. Hn: horn torus (rmajor = rminor)
3. Sp: spindle torus. (rmajor < rminor)

How would I go about correctly printing the corresponding manufacturing code to each type of torus?

Here is my current code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
//GLOABAL DECLARATIONS

 #define COST 75.25
 #define PAINT 13.65

int main()
{
   //LOCAL DECLARATIONS

   int rmajor;
   int rminor;
   int factor1;
   int factor2;
   int factor3;
   char char1;
   char char2;
   double area;
   double volume;
   double cost;
   double paint;

   //EXECUTABLES

   printf("Please input major radius (meters): ");
   scanf("%d" , &rmajor);
   printf("Please input minor radius (meters): ");
   scanf("%d", &rminor);
   printf("\n=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=\n");

   volume = (M_PI * pow(rminor,2)) * (2*M_PI*rmajor);
   area = (4 * pow(M_PI,2) * rmajor * rminor);

   factor1 = rmajor / rminor;
   factor2 = rminor / rmajor;

   factor1 = (factor1 + 2) % (factor1 + 1);
   factor2 = (factor2 + 2) % (factor2 + 1);
   factor3 = (factor1 * rmajor) + (factor2 * rminor);
   factor3 = factor3 / (factor1 + factor2);

   char1 = (factor1 * ('R' - 'A')) + (factor2 * ('H' - 'A')) + (factor3 * ('S' - 'A'));
   char2 = (factor1 * ('i' - 'A')) + (factor2 * ('n' - 'A')) + (factor3 * ('p' - 'A'));
   //printf("\nchar1: %c\n", char1);
   //printf("char2: %c\n", char2);

   cost = COST * volume;
   paint = PAINT * area;

   printf("Manufacturing Code: %c%c\n ", 'A' + char1, 'A' + char2);
   printf("Surface Area     : %13.2f\n", area);
   printf("Volume            : %13.2f\n", volume);
   printf("=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-\n");
   printf("Cost of building torus ($): %12.2f\n", cost);
   printf("Cost of painting torus ($): %12.2f\n", paint);
   printf("=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-\n");

  return(0);
}
```

Here are some of my example outputs:

```
Please input major radius (meters): 10
Please input minor radius (meters): 5

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
Manufacturing Code: ?
Surface Area      :       1973.92
Volume            :       4934.80
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
Cost of building torus ($):    371343.87
Cost of painting torus ($):     26944.02
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
52 lpvinslogin01.itap.purdue.edu ~/CS159/labs/lab03  % a.out
Please input major radius (meters): 7
Please input minor radius (meters): 7

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
Manufacturing Code: ▒▒
Surface Area      :       1934.44
Volume            :       6770.55
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
Cost of building torus ($):    509483.78
Cost of painting torus ($):     26405.14
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
```

Output 1 is supposed to be a ring torus (Ri) and Output 2 should be a horn torus (Hn).  Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Your code uses a lot of "magic" numbers and variables that don't have a clear purpose. You should consider posing a more minimal example that is easier to follow. I have no idea where to even start when figuring out what this line means: `char1 = (factor1 * (82 - 65)) + (factor2 * (72 - 65)) + (factor3 * (83 - 65));`

Comment: Why do you need three factors to compare two numbers?

Comment: Couldn't you just break down and use `if `statements instead of playing math games with ASCII characters?

Comment: Why don't you want to use logical operators?  What you're doing is far more complicated and harder to understand that doing a simple comparison.

Comment: Don't use _magic numbers_! `65` is `'A'`, use the character-constant! (same for the rest)

Comment: Can you use bit operations `|`, `>>`, and `!`?

Comment: As a guess, OP wants two characters, using ASCII math to make `char1` 'R', 'H' or 'S', and `char2` be 'i','n', or 'p'.

Comment: I can't use bit operations, logical operators, or comparisons.  I realize this seems quite pointless, but it's required.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight In the event that the numbers are the same number, I need a 3rd facor to verify this.

Comment: @MichaelWendel Are you restricted from using character literals, though? That would make your code far easier to read. As is, I don't think you'll get much help on here unless you do something to make this look more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code computes `factor1` and `factor2` incorrectly: they stay `1` when the values are equal, while multiplication inside the computation of `char1` and `char2` suggests that exactly one of `factor1`, `factor2`, and `factor3` must be `1`, and the remaining ones must be zero.

You can fix this problem by multiplying `factor1` and `factor2` by `(factor3+1)%2`:

```
factor1 = rmajor / rminor;
factor2 = rminor / rmajor;

factor1 = (factor1 + 2) % (factor1 + 1);
factor2 = (factor2 + 2) % (factor2 + 1);
factor3 = (factor1 * factor2); // rmajor == rminor
factor1 *= (factor3+1) % 2;    // rmajor > rminor
factor2 *= (factor3+1) % 2;    // rmajor < rminor

char1 = (factor1 * 'R') + (factor2 * 'S') + (factor3 * 'H');
char2 = (factor1 * 'i') + (factor2 * 'p') + (factor3 * 'n');

printf("Manufacturing Code: %c%c\n ", char1, char2);
```

Note that factoring out `'A'` from the computation lets you arrive at a much simpler forumla.

[Demo](http://ideone.com/OT0IpG).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the error in my logic!  Lines 6-8 where what I was looking for.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `factor1` and `factor2` into a single index in the range 0 to 2 as follows:

```
   int mfindex = 2 * factor1 + factor2 - 1;
```

Then it is just a matter of looking up the manufacturing code using the index.

```
   static const char mfcode[3][2] = { "Sp", "Ri", "Hn" };

   printf("Manufacturing Code: %.2s\n ", mfcode[mfindex]);
```